# Get multiple citations; [1-5] instead of [1,2,3,4,5]

Tags: biblatex

I'm using the package;

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[sorting = none, backend = bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Refs.bib}
```

to get my references. But I want to refer to multiple references so it looks like [1-5], but I get only [1,2,3,4,5].

What must I do to get the citations to look like [1-5] instead of [1,2,3,4,5]?

Comment: Use a `style` for biblatex that does that. See the section "3.3 Standard Styles" in the documentation for where that is mentioned.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want the style `numeric-comp`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[sorting = none, backend = bibtex, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
We cite three sources \cite{aristotle:anima, aristotle:physics, aristotle:poetics}.
We then cite one other source \cite{worman}. 
Finally we cite all our sources, but in a different order 
\cite{worman, aristotle:anima,aristotle:poetics, aristotle:physics}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Unrecommended way

I used the [`cite`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cite) package before the BibLaTeX+Biber times. I enclose an example.

```
% run: *latex mal-multiple-citations.tex
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt]{report}
%\usepackage[sorting=none,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% Wikipedia + http://liinwww.ira.uka.de/bibliography/
\begin{filecontents*}{Refs.bib}
@Book{abramowitz+stegun,
 author    = "Milton {Abramowitz} and Irene A. {Stegun}",
 title     = "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with
              Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables",
 publisher = "Dover",
 year      =  1964,
 address   = "New York",
 edition   = "ninth Dover printing, tenth GPO printing"
  }
@Book{hicks2001,
 author    = "von Hicks, III, Michael",
 title     = "Design of a Carbon Fiber Composite Grid Structure for the GLAST
              Spacecraft Using a Novel Manufacturing Technique",
 publisher = "Stanford Press",
 year      =  2001,
 address   = "Palo Alto",
 edition   = "1st",
 isbn      = "0-69-697269-4"
  }
@Book{Torre2008,
 author    = "Joe Torre and Tom Verducci",
 publisher = "Doubleday",
 title     = "The Yankee Years",
 year      =  2008,
 isbn      = "0385527403"
  }
@Unpublished{shidana,
  title =   "Using Neural Networks to Categorize Bulltin Board
         Message",
  author =  "shidan",
  keywords =    "neural networks",
  scope =   "appl",
  }
@Article{Horne94,
  author =  "Horne",
  title =   "On the Node Complexity of Neural Networks",
  journal = "NNETS: Neural Networks",
  volume =  "7",
  year =    "1994",
}
\end{filecontents*}
%\addbibresource{Refs.bib}

\begin{document}
Text before. \cite{abramowitz+stegun, hicks2001, Torre2008, shidana, Horne94} Text after.
\bibliography{Refs.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]